# Gulp move and backup with numbers

Tags: javascript, gulp

My Project Structure

```
dist/
app/
app/css/*
app/js/*
app/lib/*/*
app/images/*
app/index.html
app/contact.php
```

I want to move all files and folder which is under app/ to dist/version-X

I need to take last number increase 1 create new folder and put all files. Maybe as zip or tar.gz file

For now:

```
    var number = 1;
    gulp.task('move', function(){
      gulp.src('app/*', { base: './' })
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/version-' + number));
    });
    number++;
```

But I need to take folder number and increase it. like version-2 version-3 etc

As alternative I try

```
    var myVDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
    gulp.task('move', function(){
      gulp.src('app/*', { base: './' })
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/version-' + myVDate));
    });
```

But it freeze

Comment: as alternative you can use `var myVDate = new Date().getTime();`

Comment: Thank you very much it works as I want